# Android Firebase Custom Authentication Setup

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to set up firebase custom login but I cannot figure out the second step,where and how I am supposed to open web/auth.htm..,Got it from android quickstart tutorial

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38028927/edit) your question to include a link to where you got these instructions?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Comment: Ah... I didn't know we had a readme there. Thanks for clarrifying. Those instructions are for user's of the web quickstart, which is in the same repo. You can skip the second bullet point and continue with the one about Android.

Comment: I also highly recommend reading the accompanying documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth The quickstart sample and documentation are meant to be used hand-in-hand.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  on the docs after you get server keys and the json is downloaded in your computer the next step is Copy this file to your authentication server.....,How do you copy that json file to your authentication server,Its not shown in the documentation.,

Comment: To use custom authentication, you'll need to run code to mint a JSON Web Token on a server that *you* control. You need to copy the JSON file to that server.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so first you need two apps one that controls the server and client app?https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup

Comment: That is the premise of custom authentication: you already have a user database (on a server-side backend) and want to authenticate your users there. You write code on that server to authenticate the user against your own user store, then mint a JSON web token for that user. Your client-side app takes this JWT and signs in to Firebase with it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want people to create accounts and login  using phone number and password,and from what I am getting its like I have to create a server app the one I add firebase Sdk and the Json file and client app that user signs with...,